# How to access a property of a JSON object stored as environment variable from within the request body?

Tags: json, postman

Here I am storing the response object in the environment variable.

```
   let res = pm.response.json(); 
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable('currentUser', JSON.stringify(res));
```

res object has a property called "userId"

In another request body I want to set the userId to the value stored in the currentUser object. Something like this.

```
"userId": "{{currentUser.userId}}",
```

But this didn't work.

Converting to JSON also didn't work.

```
"userId": "{({JSON.parse(currentUser)).userId}}",
```

Is it possible to do this in Postman?

EDIT

There are many properties in the object that are used in different other requests. I was thinking that rather than creating environment variable for each an every one of them, if I could just save the object and pass them when needed. That was the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Do you just want that value and not the whole object?

Comment: @DannyDainton  For example rather than storing properties like userId, tenantId, subscriptions etc in seperate variables, can I store the currentUser object and access these properties when needed.

Comment: That's the type of rationale that should probably be added to the original question. The more specific information you add, would lead to a more specific answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this do the same thing for you?

```
let userId = pm.response.json().userId
pm.environment.set('currentUser', userId)
```

Then use it like this:

```
"userId": "{(userId}}"
```

Not sure what the reasoning is behind storing the whole response for a single value, within the data.

---

**Edit**

You can add this to the `Pre-request Script` of the second request:

```
pm.environment.set("userId", JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('currentUser')).userId)
```

And then reference it, in the same way as I mentioned above, within the `POST` request body.

Comment: I am aware of the above.

There are many properties in the object that are used in different other requests. I was thinking that rather than creating environment variable for each an every one of them, if I could just save the object and pass them when needed. That was the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Updated my original answer with something that will work, not the best solution but It should help.

Comment: That would still create the variables in the environment. So, I would rather just add them when I retrieve the object rather than later. Looks like what I asked was not really possible.

Comment: You could remove those either individually or everything with a `.clear()` or `.unset()` in the Tests tab of the second request. I think it's more to do with the why they are referenced in the body more that anything else. I showed that's possible to do it :)

Comment: @enzio902 - Have you found any solution for the issue of not accessing object properties directly inside request body? I have a similar scenario and using local variables for the time being.