# Using ID's from previous request in new request

Tags: request, postman

I have used Postman to extract a number of ID's from a request. Now I would like to use those ID's in a new series of requests using Postman. I can't figure out how to do this, does anyone know?

There are several hundreds of ID's and below are some examples that I can see in the console (but they do not appear in the request Body)

(100) [373894, 373893, 373467, 373459, 372712, …]

0: 373894

1: 373893

2: 373467

3: 373459

I would like to use postman to send new requests for all these ID's where I would like to fill the brackets with the ID's in the request URL that now looks like this:

[https://app.rule.io/api/v2/campaigns/{{}}/statistics](https://app.rule.io/api/v2/campaigns/%7B%7B%7D%7D/statistics)

I've tested the ID's one at a time and they work fine but I would like to run them all to then collect the data and send it to Google Data Studio. (background is that I'm trying to send campaign data from an e-mail marketing tool into Google Data Studio and combine it with website data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a property of a JSON object stored as environment variable from within the request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457903/how-to-access-a-property-of-a-json-object-stored-as-environment-variable-from-wi)

Answer (score 0):

Postman is able to run user-defined test scripts after the call performed. So you could define an array variable, add an ID each time you obtain it. And then, use that array variable to make a call with the whole bunch of IDs you have.

Take a look this blog: https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/